# How to switch Ctrl-a and Home in Eshell?

Tags: key-bindings, eshell

I tried the following, but it does not work:

```lisp
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-a") #'move-beginning-of-line)
            (local-set-key (kbd "home") #'eshell-bol)))
```

After that both keys are bound to `move-beginning-of-line`.

Answer (score 1):

Got it myself. The name of the Home key is not "`home`" but "`<home>`".

```lisp
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-a") #'move-beginning-of-line)
            (local-set-key (kbd "<home>") #'eshell-bol)))
```